# how to capture multiple images using cameraCaptureSequence for Windows Phone 8?

Tags: windows-phone-8

I am trying to using the CameraCaptureSequence API to capture a sequence of frames of a scene. Currently, I am trying to modify the code available on MSDN for the [basic lens sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/Basic-Lens-sample-359fda1b) to accomplish this.

here is what I have done to capture 3 frames. But the app crashes upon start:

```
public async Task PrepareCameraCaptureSequence()
{
 this.cameraCaptureSequence = this.PhotoCaptureDevice.CreateCaptureSequence(3);
 this.cameraCaptureSequence.FrameAcquired += cameraCaptureSequence_FrameAcquired;
 await this.PhotoCaptureDevice.PrepareCaptureSequenceAsync(this.cameraCaptureSequence);
}
```

Most of the online resources I saw do the above for just one frame, i.e., using "this.PhotoCaptureDevice.CreateCaptureSequence(1)". Can someone please help me out with capturing multiple frames using CameraCaptureSequence?

Thanks
Ekta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I have found something on [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj662940%28v=vs.105%29.aspx#BKMK_Directivesandcapabilities) MSDN article.

Apparently, the Windows.Phone.Media.Capture.CameraCaptureSequence class currently supports only single frame capture. Hence, while working with the current release of Windows 8 APIs, you must specify a single frame when you call the CreateCaptureSequence method.

That's too bad, I am guessing I will have to work with the frames of a video stream. If anyone comes across another answer to this question, please do share!